# Homework: am I misinterpreting the statement "Suppose the probability is 95% that one of the two lanes in route A will not require major resurfacing"

Tags: probability

I have been stumped by this question:

> Road $A$ has two lanes; the eastbound lane is $A_1$ and the westbound lane is $A_2$. Suppose the probability is 95% that one of the two lanes in route $A$ will not require major resurfacing.
>  Determine the probability that road $A$ will require major resurfacing in the next 2 years. Assume that if one lane of a route needs major resurfacing, the chance that the other lane of the same route will also need resurfacing is 3 times its original probability.

My current working is as follows:

> $P[(A_1∩{\bar{A_2}})∪({\bar{A_1}}∩A_2)] = 0.95$ 
> $P($Road A needs major surfacing$)$ $=$ $P(A_1∪A_2)$  $= P(A_1∩A_2)+ P[(A_1∩{\bar{A_2}})∪({\bar{A_1}}∩A_2)]$
> $P(A_1|A_2) = 3P(A_1)$
> $\frac{P(A_1∩A_2)}{P(A_2)}= 3P(A_1)$
> $P(A_1∩A_2) = 3P(A_1)* P(A_2)$

I am not sure how to proceed from here. The provided solution from the textbook is below:

> $P(A_1) = P(A_2) = 0.05$
> $P(A_2|A_1) = 0.15$ [1]
> $P($Road A needs major surfacing$)$
>  $=P(A_1∪A_2)$   [2]
> $=P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_2|A_1)*P(A_1)$
> $= 0.0.5 + 0.05 - 0.15(0.05)$
> $= 0.0925$

How were steps [1] and [2] supposed to be derived? Have I made an error in interpreting the question?

Note: the question originates from a previous edition of the textbook. The lecturer has mentioned that some questions in the textbook may have errors.